# Attach a Child of Prefab on a public Variable or Access the Child of a Prefab

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity New Editor (2018.3) Introduced nested prefabs.  Does anyone know how to assign a child of a prefab to a public variable?

For Example:

I have a Rope with a Parent GameObject and the child are on all the joints.

I want to access the rigidbody of 1 of the joints, so i set a public gameobject to access it, but i can only select the parent object instead of the child or joint.

Does anyone know how, or is there a way to access the child object of a prefab?

For Example:  my code looks like this

```
   public GameObject player;
   Rigidbody2D rb;

void Start()
{
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    rb = player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    Debug.Log(player.name);
}
```

im trying to get access to the nested prefab thats on the parent gameobject with the above code, but im getting a Null Reference Exception.  What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood the question at all, but I think I can help you with something. If you want to access a Child in a GameObject or a Joints components there is a way to do it in [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html).

Also be careful that what you have asked for is not a GameObject is a GameObject[], is an array of all the GameObjects that their tag is the same. Make sure your GameObject tag is what you are asking for and make the GameObject into an array and ask for the first one.

```
GameObject[] player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
rb = player[0].transform.GetComponent<RigidBody>();
```

I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

So i realized that i had to treat gameobjects and components differently (silly me) so i set up the code like below i was able to grab the child of the prefab

```
  void Start()
{
    checkSleeping = false;
    joint = player.transform.Find("Joint 0").gameObject;
    jointRB = joint.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    Debug.Log("Found Him");
}
```

Comment: why is Find bad?

Comment: It is very heavy on the processor, cant you reference it as a public variable?